# Dynamic URL in Open Graph og:url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

I need to publish a MP4 video on Facebook using OpenGraph.

I've created a dynamic page that gets the ID of the video and generates meta tag according to selected id.
If i insert the url like http://site/video/ID inside the Facebook sharing debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), the video is shared correctly with image preview and video player.
If i put a new id i get "This URL hasn't been shared on Facebook before." and preview does not work.

I don't think it makes sense to force Facebook to crawl for every ID, there must be a better way to do it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you try to share it Facebook will automatically try to crawl it

Comment: If i try to share it, in the preview does not appear image preview nor video preview

Comment: For images to show up on first share: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching